# Is it necessary to use worker when send mail via mailgun http api?

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I follow the laravel document to implement the mailgun service to send emails.

It is working quite well, but when my project starts growing large, I am considering some performance improvement.

When I look into the [laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker), and its example is about using it for sending emails.

And here comes to my question,

When I use mailgun http api to send emails, is it going to improve server performance if I also put the request on queues?

Comment: As far as I know, Mailgun will queue your recipients itself, so implementing a custom queue to put the recipients on the Mailgun's queue seems like an overkill.

Comment: @lesssugar I know for server to send a http api request is normally not an issue to performance problem, but even though mailgun handle the "real" sending part, the http request from my server to mailgun still contain the email's content which is larger than normal api requests. That part I wonder if it needs to be queued.

Comment: @lesssugar I disagree, for reasons that client (user of app) needs to wait until content of email is sent to mailgun servers. OP do you own the server, do you use VPS?

Comment: Simply put if you want to use queues you need a worker on server that will work behind the scenes.

Comment: @Kyslik I manage the server and it's a VPS.

Comment: Then there is no big deal, just follow the documentation. And to answer the question "is it going to improve performance?" not sure; but I am sure users of you application will welcome blazing fast response from your application (not 1-2-5 second delay waiting for mailgun servers). If you want to talk "performance" you need to define what you mean by it.